# Using JQuery Append From AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a dropdown list that populated by another dropdown list. I'm using AJAX and PHP.

I have created my AJAX file like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['selname']))
{
    include('config.php');
    $clientId = $_POST['selname'];

    $query  = "SELECT tv.*, v.* FROM t_vorder tv LEFT JOIN m_vehicle v ON tv.tv_vehicleid = v.v_id WHERE tv_orderid = '$clientId'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $namek = "";
        $namek .= $row['v_id'];
        if($row['v_jenis'] != "" || !empty($row['v_jenis']))
        {
            $namek .= ' - '.$row['v_jenis'];
        }
        if($row['v_platno'] != "" || !empty($row['v_platno']))
        {
            $namek .= ' - '.$row['v_platno'];
        }
        if($row['v_merk'] != "" || !empty($row['v_merk']))
        {
            $namek .= ' - '.$row['v_merk'];
        }
        $xx .= "<option value='$row[v_id]'>$namek</option>";
    }
    return $xx;
    exit;
}
?>
```

After that, I called this AJAX file to my main program, here's my JQuery code:

```
function getVehicle()
    {
        var selname = $("select[name=noorder]").val();
        $('#combobox2').html('');
        $.ajax({ url: "getVehicle.php",
            data: {"selname":selname},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(output) {
              console.log(output);
                $('#combobox2').append(output);
            }

        });
    }
```

And last is my HTML code:

```
<select name="noorder" id="combobox" class="form-control">
    //get my vehicle from database
    <?php
        $querycon = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM m_order WHERE o_status='1' ORDER BY o_id");
        while($rowcon = mysqli_fetch_array($querycon, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $invoice = sprintf("%s%"."04d", $rowcon['o_code'], $rowcon['o_id']);
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rowcon['o_id']; ?>"><?php echo $invoice; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="kendaraan" class="form-control" id="combobox2" onclick="getVechile();">

</select>
```

My Ajax works fine, my console log return that the file finished load. But my dropdown list not appended by Jquery. Anyone know where's my mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did't request for `json` obj/data into ajax success callback, then no need for `dataType: "json",` inside ajax properties. Remove that and change `return $xx;` into `echo $xx;`

Comment: what a shame... I already tried many times to change echo and return, but my big mistakes is I forgot to delete dataType line.... Thank You very much!!

Comment: Yeah, that makes me going crazy sometimes. You're welcome mate!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request gets data from PHP file only when its printed out on the page.

Returning and data from PHP (AJAX backend) to jQuery/Javascript does not mean anything.

Change

```
return $xx;
```

to

```
echo $xx;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `dataType: "json"` in your ajax call, so it get response in JSON. First remove `dataType: "json"` line from ajax call. Then replace `return $xx;` with `echo $xx;` in your php script.

Hope this solution may works for you, Thanks!